# ListPicker crashes on full screen - Silverlight tool kit for WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit

When implementing a ListPicker, it will crash when there are enough items to make it full screen. It does not crash if there are only 2-3 items and it just expands. I get an ArgumentException, 'The parameter is incorrect'

```
<toolkit:ListPicker Grid.Row="1" 
                    ItemTemplate="{Binding lpkItemTemplate}" 
                    FullModeItemTemplate="{Binding lpkFullItemTemplate}">
    <toolkit:ListPicker.Items>
        <toolkit:ListPickerItem>1</toolkit:ListPickerItem>
        <toolkit:ListPickerItem>5</toolkit:ListPickerItem>
        <toolkit:ListPickerItem>10</toolkit:ListPickerItem>
        <toolkit:ListPickerItem>15</toolkit:ListPickerItem>
        <toolkit:ListPickerItem>20</toolkit:ListPickerItem>
        <toolkit:ListPickerItem>30</toolkit:ListPickerItem>            
    </toolkit:ListPicker.Items>
</toolkit:ListPicker>
```

Templates are

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

    <DataTemplate x:Name="lpkItemTemplate">

        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content}" />

    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Name="lpkFullItemTemplate">

        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content}" />

    </DataTemplate>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

I've looked at examples and I havent seen anything different than what I have here and it works. The only difference is the examplesa re doing data binding. I've tried steping through the control's code but I don't see anything that pops. It throws the exception in the base class 'ItemsControl' after the 'OnManipulationCompleted' event handler has completed in the ListPicker.

Any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

FullMode only works with DataBinding, and not with static ListPickerItems.

Comment: Thats what I figured. Thank you.